# TfLite Converter TOCO Failed

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, google-colaboratory, tensorflow-lite

I’m getting an error when trying to convert a model to TensorFlow lite. This is what I typed:

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_concrete_functions([concrete_func])

tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

But I get an error that says ‘TOCO failed’. I have a model stored in google drive that I’m trying to convert. If anyone has any ideas how to fix the conversion error I’d be very grateful.

Link to Google Colab Notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1MaF0Ptr46JmFNS9hKqZ6NiAK_l0S2meD

Comment: Please share a self-contained notebook that reproduces the problem you observe.

Comment: Sure, how do I share my google colab notebook please?

Comment: @Bob Smith added :-)

Comment: Toco has been depreciated now in the 2.x version. Have you checked 2.x based converters yet?